# Análise sobre código AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Encontrei este código, que é tipo um *Long Polling*, e queria saber se posso ter problemas ao usá-lo. E também queria saber os contras desse código se eu for utilizá-lo.

`pagina.html` => página que ocorre a atualização automática

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="ajax.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    obj_online = new montaXMLHTTP();
    function Online(){      
        obj_online.open("GET","ultimasmensagens.php",true); // Na pagina ultimassenhas esta a programação que lista as informações do BD
        obj_online.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        obj_online.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(obj_online.readyState == 4){
                document.getElementById("online").innerHTML = obj_online.responseText;
                clearTimeout(re);
                setTimeout("Online()",5000);
            }
        }
        obj_online.send(null);
        var re = setTimeout("reenvia()",10000);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="setTimeout('Online()',2000);">
    <div id="online">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`ajax.js`

```
function montaXMLHTTP(){
    try{
        myObj = new XMLHttpRequest()
    }catch(e){
        myObj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    }
    return myObj;
}
```

`ultimasmensagens.php` => página que lista as mensagens

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<? 
include 'config.php'; // conexao com o bd
$mensagens = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mensagens order by idmensagem DESC limit 5") 
    or die (mysql_error());
while($minhalista = mysql_fetch_array($mensagens)){ ?>
    <?=$minhalista['titulo']?><br />
<? } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Observação sobre o PHP: é mais seguro usar **`<?php`** e **`<?php echo`** do que *`<?`* e *`<?=`*.

Comment: Sim sobre o php eu sei, mas queria saber mais sobre esse ajax ai

Comment: Como fica se houver mais que 5 mensagens após o intervalo?
No caso, você está usando Ajax polling, long polling não fecha a conexão fica aguardando o servidor responder, não sendo necessário reabrí-la a cada intervalo de tempo, gerando um excesso de requisições desnecessárias.
Recomendo dar uma olhada neste link http://imasters.com.br/artigo/23436/javascript/veja-como-o-long-polling-pode-te-ajudar-a-desenvolver-aplicacoes-em-tempo-real/

Comment: Lucas, por isso fiz só um Comentário. Uma explicação completa é publicada como Resposta ;)

Comment: Já li esse post só queria tirar uma analise desse codigo meu

Comment: Também comentei sobre o seu código. Ele gera requisições desnecessárias, consumo de processamento, banda, desnecessários, se usado em um app com muitos acessos, terá um desempenho ruim. Funcionar funciona, mas não da melhor maneira.

Comment: Entendi marcelo

Comment: brasofilo a minha duvida é que nem o marcelo ta falando os contras do código e se tem algo desnecessário no código tambem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso não é Long Polling e não recomendo a utilização do script pelo seguinte:

- Uma conexão com o servidor é estabelecida a cada 5 segundos, mesmo sem nenhuma alteração no servidor.

**Se isso fosse um chat, na prática funcionaria assim:**

1. Escrevo a mensagem e envio para você que foi a cozinha e não pode responder;
2. A cada 5 segundos o script faz uma requisição ao servidor para ver se você respondeu a minha mensagem;
3. Você demorou na cozinha cerca de 10 minutos, então são 12 requisições por minuto, ou seja, o script fez 120 requisições ao servidor sem necessidade nenhuma.
4. Você respondeu mas escreveu cerca de 3 mensagem no intervalo de 5 segundos (rápido né)
5. De repente recebo 3 mensagem de uma só vez...

**Agora veja os problemas:**

1. 120 requisições foram feitas e consumiram recursos do servidor sem necessidade nenhuma porque não houve resposta da sua parte.
2. Mensagens ficaram pendentes porque só recebo uma actualização a cada 5 segundos.
3. Varias conexões ao mesmo tempo fazendo a mesma requisição irá sobrecarregar o servidor, podendo até "derruba-lo" por falta de memória para processar todos os pedidos.

**Long polling seria diferente, na prática ficaria assim:**

1. Escrevo a mensagem e envio para você que foi a cozinha e não pode responder;
2. A ligação fica aberta a espera de uma resposta sua e não há mais requisições até que a resposta chegue;
3. Você demorou na cozinha cerca de 10 minutos, mas como só há requisições se houver uma resposta, só ocorreu 1 requisição.
4. Você respondeu mas escreveu cerca de 3 mensagem no intervalo de 5 segundos (rápido né)
5. Recebo uma resposta de cada vez, porque quando você pressionou  para enviar a primeira mensagem, houve uma alteração no servidor e a ligação que estava pendente retornou uma resposta, fechou a conexão e logo em seguida a restabeleceu recomeçando o ciclo.

Veja, só foi feita 1 requisição ao servidor, o que consumiu muito menos recursos.

Isso é uma explicação prática, procura por PHP + LONG POLLING, há muitos exemplos.

Comment: Perfeita explicação.

Comment: Muito boa sua explicação, eu sabia que esse sistema em ajax era uma coisa de 7 cabeça mesmo kkk, mas eu acabei de resolver o problema com o meu long polling aqui no forum, abreço!

Comment: @LucasC.S não é um bicho de 7 cabeças, apenas confunde-se um pouco com ajax. Mas se é para fazer uma aplicação real time, sugiro mudar esta parte de php para nodejs, é mais adequado.

Answer (score 2):

O sistema está legal, Lucas. Mas para se tornar long polling, precisar adicionar o "long". Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
include 'config.php'; // conexao com o bd
$count = 0;
// 30 tentativas ou 30 segundos até encontrar a primeira atualização.
while ($count < 30) {
    // Adicione um campo em WHERE para saber se a mensagem é nova. O ideal é uma data
    $mensagens = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mensagens WHERE creation > '$ultimaAtualizacao' order by idmensagem DESC limit 5")  or die (mysql_error());
    while($minhalista = mysql_fetch_array($mensagens)){
        echo $minhalista['titulo'];
        break;
    }

    // Não sobrecarregue seu banco. Espere 1 segundo antes de uma nova tentativa.
    sleep(1);
    $count++;
}
```

Existem muitos prós e contras neste tipo de polling. Mas acho ela bem melhor do que fazer request a cada 3 segundos, como é comum em muitos chats por aí.

O uso do websocket para ainda é instável e não funciona em todos os browsers. Eu prefiro ainda o long polling junto com nodejs

Comment: Entendi mais ainda sobre long polling com sua explicação =D

Comment: @LucasC.S eu utilizou muito, em especial, em sistemas de com filas, como notificações e chat. No chat, por exemplo, o tempo de resposta é praticamente em tempo real