# Carga do servidor em tempo real

Tags: php

Utilizando o script abaixo estou conseguindo visualizar a carga do cpu, mais estou com dúvidas na parte de atualizar o valor em tempo real, fiz uma pequena gambiarra utilizando o html para atualizar a página depois de 50 segundos, mais não é uma prática muito legal.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="50" >
```

PHP

```
<?php  
$min_warn_level = 3; 
// Set to min load average to send alert 
$email_recipient = "your@email.com"; 
 // Set to address of alert recipient
$current_reading = @exec('uptime');
preg_match("/averages?: ([0-9\.]+),[\s]+([0-9\.]+),[\s]+([0-9\.]+)/", $current_reading, $averages); 
$uptime = explode(' up ', $current_reading); 
$uptime = explode(',', $uptime[1]); $uptime = $uptime[0].', ' . $uptime[1];
$data = "Server Load Averages $averages[1], $averages[2], $averages[3]\n";
$data .= "Server Uptime $uptime"; if ($averages[3] > $min_warn_level ) {
$subject = "Alert: Load average is over $min_warn_level"; mail($email_recipient, $subject, $data); 
} 

 echo $data; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar AJAX para fazer suas requisições a esse ficheiro PHP, evitando que a página seja recarregada a cada 50 segundos.

A vantagem de se utilizar AJAX é que você reduz o tráfego entre o cliente e o servidor e por consequência, reduz a carga de processamento no servidor.

No lugar de recarregar todo o conteúdo, você apenas irá receber a resposta da requisição, que no seu caso, provavelmente será um array com os dados da carga do CPU. Com a resposta da requisição, você apenas terá que actualizar alguns elementos do seu HTML com a informação actualizada.

Utilize juntamente com a técnica de Long Polling, assim só irá fazer uma nova requisição ao servidor se houver alterações na resposta da requisição.

Veja esse link: [análise ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10496/analise-sobre-codigo-ajax).
A pergunta é sobre análise de um código AJAX, pode ser usado como exemplo, você verá algumas análises, já é fora do contexto da sua pergunta, mas está indirectamente ligado.

**Exemplo com Javascript puro:**

Na sua página onde é feito o refresh a cada 50 segundos, insira o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   o = "";
   try{ o = new XMLHttpRequest() }
   catch(e){ o = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }

   function getAjax(){
        //Troque "seu_ficheiro.php" pelo seu ficheiro PHP que verifica a carga do CPU
        //Nesse exemplo, o ficheiro PHP está no mesmo directório que o HTML onde foi inserido o Javascript, se estiver em directórios diferentes, é necessário inserir o caminho correcto.
        o.open("GET","seu_ficheiro.php",true);
        o.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        o.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(o.readyState == 4){
                //Altera somente o HTML da div que vai receber a resposta da requisição
                //No exemplo utilizamos a div com o id "resultado"
                document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = o.responseText;
            }
        }
        o.send(null);
    }
    //A cada 10 segundos será feito uma nova requisição ao servidor
    setTimeout("getAjax()",10000);
</script>
```

No seu ficheiro PHP, você tem um "echo" da variável "$data", na div "resultado" deverá aparecer o conteúdo da variável "$data".

Isso é um exemplo básico de uma requisição AJAX, não deve ser usada em larga escala para não sobrecarregar o servidor.

Não se esqueça de remover o refresh a cada 50 segundos, já não será necessário.

Comment: A explicação foi ótima, mais ainda continuo sem saber como implementar ao roteiro.

Comment: @theflash vou editar com um exemplo básico, utiliza jquery?

Comment: Pode utilizar o jquery sem problemas.

Comment: @theflash veja um exemplo prático usando javascript puro, alterei a resposta.

Comment: gostei bastante da explicação, obrigado.