# Div dinamica + php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu preciso de uma tabela que seja atualizada todo instante automaticamente, tipo a linha do tempo do facebook que atualiza sozinho.

creio que em jquery dá pra fazer isso, alguém tem alguma idéia?

Comment: Procure sobre a técnica de long polling com PHP + AJAX, deve ajuda-lo a resolver o problema.

Comment: de uma olhada aqui nesse exemplo que criei e veja se é mais ou menos isso http://jsfiddle.net/nydoz2mn/

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse post: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10496/an%C3%A1lise-sobre-c%C3%B3digo-ajax/10507#10507

Comment: rs, pensei que fosse um sistema chat mesmo, time line.... se for, seria algo do tipo: http://jsfiddle.net/r4kofh4h/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim é possível fazer com jquery e javascript, como no exemplo abaixo:

**jquery:**

```
var req = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    update();
});

function update() {
    req++;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/echo/html/',
        data: {
            html: 'Requisição: ' + req,
            delay: 0
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('div').html(data);
        }
    });
}

setInterval(function () {
    update();
}, 3000);
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/w36564us/).

Comment: A técnica de Long Polling seria melhor, dá uma olhada nessa análise: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10496/an%C3%A1lise-sobre-c%C3%B3digo-ajax/10507#10507