# Uso setInterval X WebSockets

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação PHP com AngularJS, nesta aplicação tem um sistema de mensagens. Preciso somente verificar o quantitativo de mensagem a pelo menos a cada 2 min.
Minha duvida seria, o uso do setInterval seria recomendado neste caso, ou a criação de um Socket seria melhor ?
Visto que a atualização é apenas mostrar o usuário a quantidade de mensagens não lidas e isso a cada 2 min.

Comment: Já houve uma discussão parecida, veja: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10496/an%C3%A1lise-sobre-c%C3%B3digo-ajax/10507#10507

Comment: Guilherme, nessa aplicação não haverá mais nenhum tipo de informação que tenha de ser sincronizada com a parte cliente? Título de mensagens ou outros dados necessários?

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso eu recomendo o setInterval, sabendo que o intervalo de atualizações é fixo, o Socket vai manter uma conexão aberta no seu servidor, atualizando a todo momento, por isso não vejo a necessidade do seu uso!